# git log of current branch only -- without specifying where it came from (master..)

Tags: git

I'm aware of `git log master..`. I understand that this shows all commits on the current branch that aren't in `master`. However while working with multiple long-lived branches this is annoying. Is my branch off of `master`, `develop`, `release-x.x.x`, `feature-blah`? Who knows! I don't know, I surely don't remember.

It's annoying to type different commands every time. It would be super nice if there were a way to find the commits on "my branch" and only on "my branch" without having to remember where "my branch" came from.

To simplify the problem, assume no branches branch off of the branch currently checked out. Because I intend to use this on local feature branches only.

I have a solution and will be posting it as an answer but I am curious if there's a better way.

Comment: There isn't really any one specific "better way", as the fundamental issue is that commits are on many branches simultaneously, with the set of branches that contain any given commit changing dynamically as branch names are created, deleted, or moved. There are some minor tweaks you can make, mostly just syntactic, to reduce the number of programs to run. In particular consider using `--not <hashes> --not` instead of a lot of `^<hash1> ^<hash2>` operations.

Comment: @torek "commits are on many branches simultaneously, with the set of branches that contain any given commit changing dynamically" -- I'm aware. But 99% of the time that's not the case. I'm trying to just get the commits of the feature branch I'm working  on. Assume no other branches branch off of the branch I'm on. I can edit the question with that if it helps clarify.

Comment: A model that *does* work is Mercurial's: a commit is forever tied to the branch on which you make it. This has some drawbacks: in the end, I've concluded that Git's method, flawed as it may be, is better. Git *might* be improved by adding a second (local) notion of "parent branch" of a branch, to be distinguished from what Git already calls the *upstream* of a branch. Then `git log` could default to `<parent>..HEAD` and setting the parent of the current branch would suffice for most of your uses.

Comment: Git doesn't actually have this, but it does have flexible configurations. You could make an alias that runs `git log $(git parent)..HEAD` where `git-parent` is your own script that obtains or sets this "parent" setting. The obvious way to store it is with `branch.<branch>.parent`. Calling it "parent" might be overreaching, at least at this point, but I hope the idea itself is clear.

Comment: @torek I understand that, in git, branches are little more than pointers that move over time. But I'm not trying to get info about branches that have been deleted (e.g., for some arbitrary commit, what branch was it made on). But storing it (in `.gitconfig` I guess you mean?) seems to make sense. Similar to what [Mark mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60573666/1858327), but it is nice that it's not a tag so that it doesn't clutter stuff much.

Comment: Right. This particular idea (storing a configuration `branch.<branch>.parent`, or maybe `branch.<branch>.stop` or some such) is just a way to tell your local Git: "I want to treat this range of commits, delimited by parent..branch, as the set to use most of the time." The parent or stop could be a raw hash ID or a name; the name would be resolved the same way gitrevisions (or `git rev-parse`) resolves all names.

Comment: @torek I used this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60608882/1858327) and it works quite nicely. Also got a form to update the "parent" when you rebase as well. Thanks for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 3):

Your question implies a concept of a commit "belonging to" a branch, or a branch being made up of commits.  This is perhaps how other tools view the world, but git really doesn't work that way.  Since I understand it's how you want to view the commits, I'll try to address the question in that spirit, but understand that there will be no good solution to this problem because git itself doesn't "remember" which branch is your branch's "parent".

So... your own answer is flawed in two ways.  I'll address those, and then I'll suggest a another approach that might work better (though, imo, still not perfectly).

*The problems with your answer:*

First, it may not always get quite what you're after.  What if a branch was created *from* your branch?

```
O -- x -- x -- x <--(master)
      \
       A -- B -- C -- D <--(your_branch)
             \
              x -- x <--(other_branch)
```

In this picture - again if we assume that commits and branches relate in the way your question suggests - you would view `your_branch` as `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, right?  But if you give `log` exclusions for all branches' merge bases with `your_branch`, one of the merge bases is `B`, so `A` and `B` would be excluded.

This picture also illustrates why there is no real solution to the problem as posed.  I've used visual cues to imply that `other_branch` was created from `your_branch` rather than the other way around, but as far as how git stores its data, this picture is the same as one where `your_branch` is thought to be created from `other_branch`

```
O -- x -- x -- x <--(master)
      \
       A -- B -- x -- x <--(other_branch)
             \
              C -- D <--(your_branch)
```

So nothing git stores can tell whether you want to see `A` and `B` or not.

I'll add, even if you say "ah, but I never do that", another possible problem occurs if you ever merge a branch back to its parent but then continue working on it.  All commits from before the merge would be excluded from your output.

Second, it's overly-complicated.  Instead of excluding "the merge base between <each other branch> and my branch", why not just exclude each of the other refs?

*A different approach:*

If git doesn't store enough information to do what you want, then the best you can do is to follow a disciplined approach to deliberately store additional data.  For example, you could create an alias for branching so that every time you create a branch `some_branch`, you also immediately create a lightweight tag `some_branch_root`.  Then you can always log `some_branch_root..some_branch`.

Even then if you have side branches that get merged back into `some_branch` you'd see them.  You could mitigate that by giving `log` the `--first-parent` option, but then if you merge your branch into something else and then fast-forward your branch over that merge you'll have even bigger problems.

The biggest problem with this approach is that the tags would have to be moved if ever you rebase your branch, and probably should be deleted if ever you delete your branch.  Again a combination of scripting and/or just deciding not to do certain things could mitigate the problem.

So I'd say this solution is much simpler and gets you closer (say 95% of the way) to what you want; but still it only works if you can make some assumptions about how branching and merging is done in your repo.

Comment: "I'd say this solution is much simpler" I hardly think creating a tag for each branch is "simple" haha. But I can see making aliases that both makes a branch and a tag as well as one that deletes a branch and the tag. Also, good suggestions about just excluding the branches instead of the ancestors as well as using first parent to make mergers *into* my branch make sense.

Answer (score -1):

This method is cleaner but unfortunately will only work for new branches going forward.

Essentially we store "metadata" about the branch our branch came from. We store it in the local repository's config under `branch.BRANCH_NAME.parent`. This is nicer than using tags since it doesn't clutter our history. Also git will automatically handle deleting it when the branch is deleted.

We can "send parameters" to a git alias if we use a function in it. First we note the current branch (as later in the script it will be the new branch).

`git make-branch foo` will make your branch and note the parent. `git log-my-branch` will do logging and `git rebase2 bar` will reset the parent after it rebases. For these you can give extra parameters but the name of the branch must be first.

### `.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    # ...other aliases...
    make-branch = "!f() { \
    parent=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); \
        git switch -c ${1} && git config branch.$1.parent $parent ; \
    }; f"
    log-my-branch = !git log $(git config branch.$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD).parent)..HEAD
    rebase2 = "!f() { \
        git rebase $@ && git config branch.$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD).parent $1 ; \
    }; f"
```

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger how so? That can mean a lot of different things.

Comment: Settigns don't push or fetch.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger This is meant for checking logs locally on personal branches. The fact that the settings don't push or fetch is actually a good thing.

Comment: Or so you'll think until the first time you have to re-clone.  Look, if you want to claim it's a good solution for you, then use it; doesn't change my comment or my opinion of the solution.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger If I have to reclone then I don't mind taking the extra time to figure out which branch something came from since I am already getting something set up.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I'm not trying to convince you it is a good solution for you, I'm trying to relieve any concerns you have about what might be wrong with this. This *does* work (to  the extent I tested). So I'm confused why you insist on downvoting it. And honestly, maybe it wasn't you, but the timings of the rep changes to the question/answer line up with your answer/comments. It's just frustrating to encounter a problem and come up with a fix, share it with the community for people struggling with the same thing and just get downvoted because "it doesn't work with remote repos".

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I didn't say I wasn't trying to convince you of anything, I said I wasn't trying to convince you it was a good solution for you. "people are going to expect it's safe to re-clone" You make it sound like it is going to break something by calling it "unsafe", I assure you that nothing will. If the concern really is just that people are going to assume this works with other people's branches then I'll update "but unfortunately will only work for new branches going forward" to say something "will only work with new branches you create locally and only in your local repository"

Answer (score -3):

This works but isn't simple. There may not be a simple way. Also I am only 99% sure it's correct. Unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60608882/1858327) answer it works for branches that already exist.

Using `git merge-base` we can find the best (i.e., most recent in history) ancestor between two commits. If we run this between `HEAD` (the current branch) and each other branch then we find a set of commits where things split.

Below we use the `for-each-ref` command since it is better for scripting and we execute the command. We also filter out the current commit.

```
git for-each-ref --shell --format='git merge-base HEAD %(refname)' refs/heads/ | sh | sed /"$(git rev-parse HEAD)"/d
```

When using `git log` we can give it commits to include the history of and ones to *not* include the history of. So if we tell it to include the history of `HEAD` and *not* the history of the of the merge-bases we mentioned before then we have all commits only reachable by the current branch. Below is an example showing how to get everything from `HEAD` but not from `ABC` and `123`

```
git log HEAD ^ABC ^123
```

Using this alias we can get what we want. There's way too many quotes in that to figure out the command to escape them correctly so I just manually pasted it into my `~/.gitconfig`

### `.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    # ...other aliases...
    log-my-branch = !git log HEAD $(git for-each-ref --shell --format='git merge-base HEAD %(refname)' refs/heads/ | sh | sed /"$(git rev-parse HEAD)"/d | sed 's/^/^/' | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

Then just run `git log-my-branch` to get it. You can also do `git log-my-branch --graph --decorate` to customize it. Or put it in the alias if you want.

---

Some caveats of this are that if you have local versions of branches that branched off yours it will behave strangely.

If you want it to do remotes as well then remove `refs/heads/`. For example, if you only keep a local branch of your branch but have the remotes of the others. Not sure how helpful that would be.

Comment: As a reminder, downvoters are encouraged to share what issues they have with an answer so that it can be improved.